# What is this bunny icon, next to my internet usage speed?

Tags: applications, notification-icons, app-icons

A weird bunny logo has been appearing next to my internet speed lately, and I have no clue what it is.
Also, I don't use any kind of VPN.
I have tried googeling, but there isn't anything like that.

I own a Xiaomi redmi note 8 pro

[image: Bunny Icon]

Comment: Bumpidy Bump, need to get this up

Comment: Hello Rasmus. Can you give us the full high quality screenshot instead of a cropped one? That icon is already very small and zooming on it kind of pixelates it. If some of us would want to crop the icon (as it is in the current image) further for reverse image search the accuracy of the results would probably suffer a lot. Also, do tell us which Android version  and MiUI version you are using.

Comment: don't be [scared](https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=frank+the+rabbit)